# Cannot read from redirected stdout

Tags: python

I have no experience with `os.pipes()`, so some help would be greatly appreciated.

The problem: I want to redirect the stdout of my process to a pipe, and read it from the other end. My first draft is this code. I seem to write to the write end of the pipe, but then i am unable to read it from the read end, and the read call blocks.. I guess there is some stupid mistake - which comes from my lack of understanding of how this works.

```
import os
import time


r, w = os.pipe()
w = os.fdopen(w, 'w')
r = os.fdopen(r, 'r')


os.dup2(w.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
a = "Now printing ...\n"
print a
b = os.read(r.fileno(), 10)
if b.find(a) == -1:
    raise 'Could not work!'

w.close()
r.close()
```

**Edit:** got the mistake. I did not set `sys.stdout` to the new `fd`. The following line fixed it:

```
sys.stdout = w.fileno()
```

Comment: You're probably running into output buffering problems. Does it work if you call `sys.stdout.flush()` after printing?